# I am a UK citizen living in the Netherlands with my Indonesian wife we both have permanent residence

Tags: uk, entry-permit

What UK holiday visitor entry requirements will she need following brexit? We will remain residents in the Netherlands.

Comment: Any answer here would be speculation. My personal speculation would be a Standard Visitor Visa, but we shall see.

Comment: Yes true. It's difficult to make travel plans at the moment. There is a possibility of dual nationality https://www.dutchnews.nl/news/2018/09/dutch-to-publish-modernised-dual-nationality-plans-next-spring/ . In that case I would have EU citizenship and my wife could travel with an article 10 or 20 permanent residence ID card plus supporting paperwork, wedding certificate, bank statements and contracts of employment in the Netherlands.See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residence_card_of_a_family_member_of_a_Union_citizen

Comment: Why would the UK care about Family Member of EU Citizen" status after it has left the EU? (other than if it signs up to some treaty obligation when leaving).

Comment: https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa/y/indonesia/tourism/yes/no You should act immediately.

Comment: It will be after the transition period, so far as I know from Dutch immigration, that whatever reciprocal agreements will come into practise. Our permanent residence permits will be renewed during that time.

Comment: Micheal Hampton, this our current situation https://www.gov.uk/government/publications/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card/entering-the-uk-as-the-holder-of-an-article-10-residence-card no visa required my wife travels with an article 20 permanent residence ID card plus supporting paperwork, wedding certificate, bank statements and contracts of employment in the Netherlands